# React native navigator memory can't release

Tags: memory-management, react-native, navigator

My application is using navigatorios. Whenever new scene push to the stack, it didn't release memory. It seems intuitive, cause it allowing you to pop it back to previous route. I tried to use replace instead of push, however, the title won't change.

Is there any workaround on my case? 
Requiremnent: Change the title on every route

Edit:

In my application, there are several sections and for each section has different navigator title.

```
<NavigatorIOS
    ref='nav'
    initialRoute={{
    component: component,
    title: title,
    }}
/>
```

To change the title, i use push to show next section. Memory meter in xcode showing it's using more and more.

```
this.refs.nav.push({
    component: component,
    title: title,
    });
```

Answer

Finally changed to use Navigator instead of NavigatorIOS. Using replace instead of push.

Answer (score 0):

can you show your code here so that we can diagnose your problem thoroughly?

anyhow, changing title on every route is easy with Navigator, in your root Navigator component, define your routes.

```
const routes = {
  Movies,
  Contact
};
```

Create a custom component inside your renderScene method

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    let Component = routes[route.name];
    return <Component navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}/>
  }
```

As you can see the renderScene method passes some props and this is the place you pass your title to the next screen.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I've add more info on the case.

Comment: The memory is accumulating is because you did not release the route. Imagine the entire navigator as a stack, what your code is doing is keep adding more items into that stack. To resolve this, you need to pop up the particular item one by one, or reset the entire stack, whichever applicable to your application.